# Find earliest answer on question

Tags: support

I recently asked a pretty simple [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210202/change-integer-in-bitset) on SO. When I checked again, I saw that it had been successfully answered by two people. Unfortunately, the time for both says `x minutes ago`, without differentiating who answered first. Is there any way I can figure this out so that I may accept that as the correct answer. Since all answers are near identical (as the question was quite easy), I feel this is an appropriate measure to award an answer as accepted.

Comment: So tempted to add exactly the same answer again, even though there is a time elapse, but that is just my bad sense of humour.  Good question :)

Answer (score 11):

#### Method #1

[image]

Sort answers by time posted, oldest-first. Note that you'll have to unaccept any currently-accepted answer first, or it will appear first in the list regardless of sort order.

#### Method #2

[image]

Hover over the timestamp, and a more precise time will appear. If the actual creation dates differ by at least 1 second, you'll be able to identify the first this way.

#### Method #3

Just accept the best / most-useful answer regardless of when it was posted. Being fast is nice, but putting a bit more effort into creating a more detailed or better-written answer is just as laudable. And if, for instance, one author came back and revised his quickly-written answer to provide additional information or clean up mistakes, you may wish to reward this over an initially-similar hit-and-run answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by the "oldest" by selecting the appropriate sorting tab:

[image: Oldest Sort]

This will sort the oldest (first) answer to the top, assuming that you haven't already selected an answer as the accepted answer. An accepted answer will appear first (as long as it isn't your own)